# Lua toString exception for boolean value

Tags: c++, lua

I wrote a simple lua function which uses 'C++' function to execute. As my intention of creating a 'C++' function is to use the same across all lua functions to update the 'C++' variables. It works fine for numbers, but when I tried it for boolean values, it give me exception when convert to string.

Here is my code snippet.

C++ code.

```
#include <lua.hpp>
/* the Lua interpreter */
lua_State *luaState;
std::map<lua_State *, CLuaTest *> luaFbtlookup;

void CLuaTest::CLuaTest() {
  // initialize Lua 
  luaState = luaL_newstate();
  lua_register(luaState, "get_value", get_value);  // func to get values
  lua_register(luaState, "set_value", set_value);  // func to set values
  // load Lua base libraries 
  luaL_openlibs(luaState);
  luaL_dofile(luaState, "C:\LuaTest.lua");
  luaFbtlookup.insert(make_pair(luaState, this));
}

 int get_value(lua_State *L);
 int set_value(lua_State *L);

 extern "C++" int get_value(lua_State *L)
 {
     string lightName = lua_tostring(L, 1);
     FbTLuaLookup::iterator iter = luaFbtlookup.find(L);
     if (iter != luaFbtlookup.end()) {
         lua_pushstring(L, iter->second->getValueFrom(lightName).c_str());
         return 1;  // do not return zero
     }
     return 1;
 }

 extern "C++" int set_value(lua_State *L)
 {
     string lightName = lua_tostring(L, 1);
     if (NULL == lua_tostring(L, 2))
     {
         printf("WARNING : Invalid String Argument / Cannot convert arg#2 to string");
     }
     else {
         string value = lua_tostring(L, 2);

         FbTLuaLookup::iterator iter = luaFbtlookup.find(L);
         if (iter != luaFbtlookup.end()) {
             iter->second->setValueTo(lightName, value);
             lua_pushnumber(L, true);
             return 1;  // do not return zero
         }
     }
     return 1; 
 }

CLuaTest::ExecuteScript(enum Seq) {
  switch(Seq) {
    case 0:
      lua_getglobal(luaState, "AllLightsOff");
    break;

    case 1:
      lua_getglobal(luaState, "RedLightOn");
    break;

    case 2:
      lua_getglobal(luaState, "AmberLightOn");
    break;

    case 3:
     lua_getglobal(luaState, "GreenLightOn");
    break;
  }
}
```

My lua script:

```
function AllLightsOff
  set_value("RedLight", 0)
  set_value("AmberLight",0)
  set_value("GrenLight",0)
end

function RedLightOn
  set_value("RedLight", 1)
  set_value("AmberLight",0)
  set_value("GrenLight",0)
end

function AmberLightOn
  set_value("RedLight", 0)
  set_value("AmberLight",1)
  set_value("GrenLight",0)
end

function GreenLightOn
  set_value("RedLight", 0)
  set_value("AmberLight",0)
  set_value("GrenLight",1)
end
```

Things work fine with the above code, but when I tried to change the set value to use boolean values like **set_value("RedLight", False)** I get warning message printing. Should I need to pass `False` as string?

Comment: What is the warning message? Is it the `"WARNING : Invalid String Argument / Cannot convert arg#2 to string"` message in your C++ code or something else?

Comment: @KeithThompson: It's in my C++ code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua doesn't have `False`, so it simply tries to read global `_G["False"]` which is of course `nil`.

It has `false` keyword, however, but it wouldn't work either: [`lua_tostring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_tolstring) is working only for numbers and strings.

We don't see `setValueTo` code, so it is hard to guess how it works.

- If you simply want to pass `bool` value to it, use [`lua_toboolean`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_toboolean), but be aware that it treats `0` as `true` (as Lua in general).
- If you want to pass `"True"` or `"False"` as strings, then yes, you must write `set_value("RedLight", "False")`

As a side note, consider reading [how to implement lua_CFunction protocol](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_CFunction). Now, if `get_value` can't find `lightName`, it will return the last passed parameter as its result.